# Selecting Override Record(s)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Selecting records with column value NOT NULL vs one that are NULL

It sounds like a typical SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column IS NOT NULL...but not quite

Below is a table that represents a portion of data that I need to work with.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Index</td>
    <td align="center">A</td>
    <td align="center">B</td>
    <td align="center">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">0</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">3</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">4</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">5</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">6</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">7</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Index 0 record represent the default record that everyone would use if there was no override value for A, B, or C

I am always querying with values for A, B & C  but if nothing is found I want the NULL record OR NULL value combination.

By the way I am trying to do this SQL-Server 2005.

I have been trying something like

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (A = 1 OR A IS NULL)  OR (B = 1 OR B IS NULL)  OR (C = 1 )

The actual query is a cross join of 4 tables...so the table of values represent the final part of what I am trying to solve.

Also Index 0 represent the result if nothing matches...but I could have more that one record return and process further in php

Comment: Show the SQL that you're trying to use.  One way to accomplish this would be to union the 0 record always order by index desc and return top 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your where clause has the intent to always return 1 or 0 records...
simply union the index 0 always and select the top 1 descending.  This will always return 1 record and it will always be the 1 matching criteria OR the 0, unless your where clause returns more than 1 record, in which case this will return the highest index matched.

```
SELECT Top 1 * 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
  WHERE A=A AND B=B AND C=C

  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE INDEX=0) B
ORDER BY index desc;
```

Comment: I can't define index=0 explicitly I need to find it...also there could be more that one record return.